# How to keep a websocket connection alive?

Tags: android, service, websocket, push

I have an Android app, instant messaging is one of the key features. For implementing the IM feature, we use our push server based on `websocket`.

For my app, I have a PushService, in this service, I establish a `websocket` connection which connects to the push server and receive push message.

The code works well when app in foreground (i.e.: works well while user plays with the app), but when the app doesn't in foreground, it stop receiving push messages after a while (about 1 minute). Same issue when user turns off screen.

I have set a repeat task with `AlarmManager`, which checks the `websocket` connection status, if it is not in connected status, then re-try to connect so as to back to normal to receive push messages.

This works well below Android M, for example on the Android 5 phones, it seldom misses push messages. But on Android M / Android N, it doesn't work as good as on Android 5.x. I can confirm the service itself is keep running , check from the 'Running services'.

I've noticed that starts from Android M, Android introduces Doze and Standby mode, not sure if they are related, if yes, how can I make the app continue to work again? On my phone the WeChat and Skype Android App work well, what's the mechanism behind it? I know FCM is the best solution, but I cannot use that for customers in China, so I need a workaround.

Edit: I had proposed to use a foreground service but PM doesn't like the notification tray always being shown in the status bar he wants to keep it clean.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you need to register a foreground service. This previous question may help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46780547/2012017

Comment: @JustinHeath, Thanks for your comment. I had proposed PM to use foreground service but got refused as he doesn't like a notification tray to keep the status bar clean. (I'll edit my question to avoid using foreground)

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @SilviaH, sorry no, I didn't find a solution to run on Android N / O. Switching to FCM but, the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about WeChat or Skype communication, but i know the WhatsApp using you own service notification with the same tecnology of FCM.
They using the Jaber server with implements the XMPP communication protocols

[link](https://www.quora.com/Does-WhatsApp-use-GCM-to-exchange-messages)

Comment: Thanks. However seems like what you mentioned is more about the server side implementation?